# Customizing admin look and feel for just one particular type of user

Tags: customization, wp-admin

Is it possible to change the admin look and feel for just one particular type of user or a group of users.

This is not a major requirement for what I am doing at present but a nice to have feature. Just wanted to know if it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like an almost duplicate of [Back End Interface Plugin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/89342/12615).

In toscho's Answer, you'd only need to add a verification for your user's role:

```
if( current_user_can( 'custom_capability' ) )
{
    $settings = new stdClass;
    // etc
}
```

The plugin [MP6](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/mp6/), which explores the future core interface, uses a similar approach and enforces the Admin Color Scheme with the filter `get_user_option_admin_color`.

**And**, I just saw that MP6 uses bits (not sure how much) of toscho's [Clean Admin](https://github.com/toscho/T5-Clean-Admin), another cool theme for the dashboard.

Just like the first example, both plugins can be adapted to use a conditional admin theme based on the user role.

Comment: Well, looks like @toscho is all over the place in regards to admin themes. We are just a bunch of lucky bastards to have him aboard in [wordpress.se] :o)